# Build Menu Strip based on Server Directory

Tags: vb.net, windows, tree, menustrip

I'm looking for a simple way to build out my MenuStrip in VB.NET (Windows Form) Application without having to keep compiling and redistributing the application each time. Therefore I want to build the MenuStrip based on how my directories are laid out on the server. Now I don't know how many submenus I may have, so I'd like to program it to the point where it will account for N submenus.

For example...

The directories on the server are as follows:

```
Model1
  Model 1A
  Model 1B
  Model 1C
    Model 1CA
    Model 1CB
Model 2
  Model 2A
    Model 2B
      Model 2N
Model 3
```

So basically the menu strip will look like this:

```
Model1                      Model2                            Model3
  Model1A                     Model2A
  Model1B                            Model2B 
  Model1C                                   Model2N
         Model 1CA
         Model 1CB
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a TreeView control instead.

Comment: It's a matter of looping and making controls. Do you know how to make them in code?

Comment: i found a post on here that shows how to go through the directories (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710821/how-would-i-dynamically-load-the-subitems-of-a-menustrip-at-run-time). I'm just not sure how I would set it up to loop in N sub directories.

Comment: and a TreeView will not be able to work in this scenario.